# Windows boot menu instead of grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

Is it possible to switch boot loaders from grub to windows? I do know if such a thing exist but it would be nice to have that option.

Answer (score 0):

If they are booting from two different hard drives, setting the Ubuntu hard drive as top-priority in your BIOS will load the GRUB bootloader. If done correctly, GRUB should look something like

> Windows 7 (loader)
>   Ubuntu 13.04